# Question about moving events from redis to kafka

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, event-sourcing, distributed-transactions

I have a question related to a tricky situation in an event-driven system that I want to ask for advise. Here is the situation:

In our system, I use `redis` as a memcached database, and `kafka`a as message queues. To increase the performance of redis, I use `lua scripting` to process data, and at the same time, push events into a blocking list of redis. Then there will be a process to pick redis events in that blocking list and move them to kafka. So in this process, there are 3 steps:

1) Read events from redis list

2) Produce in batch into kafka

3) Delete corresponding events in redis

Unfortunately, if the process dies between 2 and 3, meaning that after producing all events into kafka, it doesn't delete corresponding events in redis, then after that process is restarted, it will produce duplicated events into kafka, which is unacceptable. So does any one has any solution for this problem. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using Kafka transaction features? Perhaps you should delete the Redis data once it gets into memory before for the Kafka producer sends it

Comment: @cricket_007: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid that in that case, if the process dies right after I delete redis data, then when it restarts, it will lose all the deleted events, because the buffer is cleared, and we haven't produced those events yet :-(

Comment: That's your only other alternative I see here... Either you remove the events and fail to send them, or you always send them, but risk duplicates. Other option would be to have some secondary store that records/caches the events that need to be removed, then send only that subset rather than rely on the original data

Answer (score 0):

**Kafka is prone to reprocess events, even if written exactly once.** Reprocessing will almost certainly be caused by rebalancing clients. Rebalancing might be triggered by:

- Modification of partitions on a topic.
- Redeployment of servers and subsequent temporary unavailabilty of clients.
- Slow message consumption and subsequent recreation of client by the broker.

In other words, if you need to be sure that messages are processed exactly once, you need to insure that at the client. You could do so, by setting a partition key that ensures related messages are consumed in a sequential fashion by the same client. This client could then maintain a databased record of what he has already processed.

Comment: In my application, to make sure the order of the events, I actually use only one partition. So I think your answer is not really related to my question, because I need to move the events in batch(batch size is 1000, for example) from redis to kafka. So if step 3 is not processed when step 2 is processed, then not only I have duplicated events, but also the event order is not correct, too

Comment: If you only use one partition than your messages will be consumed by only one consumer in sequential fashion - so that makes live easier (and slower). Nevertheless, the gist of my answer might still apply to your problem, which is: rather than trying to make your producer more robust, try to make your consumer idempotent.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point now. Thanks a lot. By the way, do you have any other suggestion for event store which can ensure exactly-once delivery?

Comment: The most common approach for exactly-once would be to keep track of records that you have processed in a database. So if a message is being consumed twice you check in the database whether the respective item was already processed. In theory, it is also possible to store the last processed offset in a database and when starting your consumer pick things up from that offset with consumer.seek(partition, offset-from-db)

Comment: Storing and seeking to offsets is when you are consuming from a Kafka topic, though, not when sourcing data from other systems such as Redis. For the case of the quesiton, a separate Redis instance could be used as those "to process" / "processed" queues